# Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute: null HttpContext.Current?

Tags: asp.net, null, httpcontext, prerequesthandler

Is it safe to always assume that HttpContext.Current will be non-null in Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute?

**EDIT:** Assuming ASP.NET webforms (not MVC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, unless you're running the code outside of the asp.net pipeline (in unit tests or some such).

The `HttpApplication` is handed an `HttpContext` upon creation.

Answer (score 1):

There has to be a current httpcontext object if the app is running.